# Hibernate refresh?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping

I am working with hibernate and mysql to abstract a database for use in a java driven website. I got all my queries to work out just fine using hibernate, but couldn't seem to figure out how to do the updates, inserts, and deletes with it so I ended up making my own bean that does those functions using regular mySQL methods.

The issue I am running into now is that when I do an update or insert using regular mysql, the persisted hibernate objects from the database do not get updated, but the data stored in the database does. How can I resynchronize or "refresh" the hibernate information to match the mysql information?

Or if it would be easier, how do I save/update modified objects from hibernate into msql. (obviously I'm new to hibernate) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 3):

Persisting the data back using standard SQL seems to somewhat defeat the purpose of using Hibernate.  My recommendation would be to change things so that you can do both retrieval and saving of data through Hibernate. Depending on your setup it could be as easy as getting a session from the session factory and calling the save method.

i.e.

```
  Session session = sessionFactory.getSession();
  session.save(hibernateObject);
```

In my experience the Hibernate documentation is quite good.  Skimming through it would probably be a worthwhile endeavor.  Particularly this section: [Chapter 10: Working with Objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html)

Comment: Just as a side note... are you doing this as a part of a web application that also uses another framework like Spring?  If so, you might consider utilizing Spring's Hibernate integration might be helpful for the session management aspect of things.

Comment: No, I'm not using Spring with this project. It's kind of too late to be adding it in I think. :(

Comment: I don't know what the environment you are working with is... so I just figured I would throw that out there.  Just in case you were using Spring and did not realize that integration was an option.  I would try the code I listed above and see how it works for you.  I'm no hibernate expert myself (at least not when it comes to configuring things from scratch... actually in the progress of learning that myself now)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hibernateSession.refresh(yourObject)
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29